# Connecting mongoose to AWS documentDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl, mongoose, aws-documentdb

I am trying to connect a NodeJS server to an AWS documentDB cluster with TLS enabled. The NodeJS server is hosted on an EC2 instance and it's on the same VPC as the documentDB cluster. But I'm getting the following error:

```
{ MongoServerSelectionError: unable to get local issuer certificate
     at Timeout.waitQueueMember.timer.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/home/ubuntu/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:438:30)
     at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
     at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
     at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
   name: 'MongoServerSelectionError',
   reason:
    TopologyDescription {
      type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
      setName: null,
      maxSetVersion: null,
      maxElectionId: null,
      servers:
       Map {
         '*******.cluster-****.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
      stale: false,
      compatible: true,
      compatibilityError: null,
      logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
      localThresholdMS: 15,
      commonWireVersion: null } }
```

The error seems to be with the TLS certificate. But I'm passing the contents of `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` while connecting as shown in the following code:

```
uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI || process.env.Db_url;
options = {
    user: "****",
    pass: "****",
}
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
mongoose.connect(
  uri,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    sslCA: [fs.readFileSync("/home/ubuntu/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem")],
  },
  err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Connection Error: ', err);
    } else {
      console.log(`Successfully Connected============`);
    }
  }
);
```

I've tried connecting to the mongo cluster using mongo shell on EC2 instance using

```
mongo --ssl --host *******.cluster-****.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 \
--sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username ***** --password *****
```

and this is working. So, the connection to the cluster is fine, but the mongoose cannot connect.

Is there any other way to connect to documentDB using mongoose?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same exact scenario

Answer (score 1):

Can you add ssl: true ? Something like this works for me:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@docdb_uri',
      {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          ssl: true,
          sslValidate: true,
          sslCA: `/usr/local/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of mongoose that you are using? In my project, mongoose 5.x works just fine but once it is updated to 6.x it won't connect to the documentdb.

Note: mongoose version < 6.4.6 is considered vulnerable. https://security.snyk.io/package/npm/mongoose

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: We eventually shifted to an in house mongodb cluster. I think Document DB doesn't have enough resources or a community to fall back to, in case the team's stuck